# Is it correct to have a static function declared in a header file?

Tags: c, static, header-files

Someone was recently reviewing a bit of code I am working on and told me that I should move some function declarations to the header file and call them static. Is the the preferred way of formatting c code and header files?

Per their suggestions my code now roughly looks like this:

`header.h`

```
# define USED_ONLY_IN_FILE1
# define USED_IN_BOTH

extern uint8_t var_used_in_both_files;
extern volatile uint8_t buffer_in_both_files[16];

static void funct_used_only_in_file1(void); //This used to live in file1.c without the static keyword
void funct_used_in_both_files(void);
```

`file1.c`

```
#include "header.h"

uint8_t var_used_in_both_files;
volatile uint8_t buffer_in_both_files[16];

void funct_used_only_in_file1(void)
{
    var_used_in_both_files++;
}

void funct_used_in_both_files(void)
{
    buffer_in_both_files[0] = 1;
}
```

`file2.c`

```
#include "header.h"

void funct_b (void)
{
    var_used_in_both_files+=2;
    funct_used_in_both_files();
}
```

It feels a little weird to me that I now have a function essentially being declared `static` in both `.c` files when `header.h` is included. I'm still wrapping my head around keywords like `static`, `extern`, and `volatile` so I'd really appreciate an explanation of why we would want a function that's used only in one file to be declared in a header file then marked `static`. Why would we want this?

Comment: There is a practice of having `static inline` functions in headers, not `static`. Other than that having anything but declarations in the headers is usually not a good idea.

Comment: You should show the reviewer this question, and ask them if that's what they intended. I don't think it is what they intended.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Deos that mean I should basically take out everything from my header.h except the `void funct_used_in_both_files(void);` ?

@uneven_mark in header.h I have `static void funct_used_only_in_file1(void);` which I used to have declared at the top of file1.c as just  `void funct_used_only_in_file1(void);`

Comment: @Indigo No, your header is containing only declarations.

Comment: @Indigo I misread your question!